# Save string variable after app close swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, variables

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

       @objc func handleLogin(){
               let mainTableVC = MainTableViewController()
               mainTableVC.chipInfoString = self.chipField.text
               let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainTableVC)

               self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: {

                        })
}

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {

        var chipInfoString:String?

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child(chipInfoString!)
}
```

After logging in, `MainTableViewController` opens. I get `chipInfoString` from `LoginViewController`. After closing the application I want the `chipInfoString`(`MainTableViewController`) value to get registered.

Comment: Store it in `UserDefaults`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you an example with UserDefaults. Have these functions in the ViewController class or where you need them. For those who are not already familiar UserDefaults can store data on device. It is not a DB tho...

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        storeValue()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        recallValue()
    }


    func storeValue(){
        UserDefaults.standard.set(wage.text!, forKey: "wage")

        // UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() - obsolete, might need to check documentation 
    }

    func recallValue(){
        wage.text! = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "wage")!

    }
```

On changes, the string will be stored and restored upon app restart. Hope it works!

Comment: How do I keep the memory in MainTableViewController in another class? @ISS

Comment: Like saving a string?

Comment: I need to recall wage.text in your example in another class

Comment: Use UserDefaults.standard.set(wage.text!, forKey: "wage") where you instantiate that class.

Comment: function does not work. memory So I have to do both a recall and a store in a class.